# Converting type XSSFCell to String java

Tags: java, excel, type-conversion, apache-poi

I'm new to Apache POI and HttpClient, and I'm confused. My program is supposed to get the value from an excel cell, and use that value in the HttpGet request. Here is the method that isn't working:

```
public String censusIdValue(int rowNumber) throws IOException {
    InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("/Users/john/Documents/Censusplaces (1).xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
    XSSFWorkbook test = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFRow row; 
    XSSFCell cell;

    String value = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(rowNumber).getCell(3); 

   return value;
}
```

wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(rowNumber).getCell(3); is type XSSFCell, and I need to convert it to a string. Is this possible or did I go about pulling this value incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void getvalFromEcelSheet(){
    File file= new File("pass here path of directry");
    FileInput input=new FileInput(file);
    XSSFWorkBook book=new XSSFWorkBook(input);
    XSSFSheet sheet=book.getSheet("Sheet1");
    XSSFRow row1=sheet.getRow(1);



XSSFCell cell=row1.getCell(1);
    String value=cell.toString();
    //we got String Value from Excelsheet
  }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix. 
    String value = 
    wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(rowNumber).getCell(3).getStringCellValue();

Comment: Cell.ValueType DateTime throw error for StringCellValue() value. (at least in port for .net)